# Getting substrings of each Array-Element

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, google-sheets, substring

I am trying to convert data stored in "dd.mm.yy" format to "w" format in Google Sheets/Appscript. Unfortunately I cannot use the ".formatDate()" function since sheets does not recognice the input values as date values, so I tried the following:

```
function CheckWeekNuber() {
   
 
  var dateStr =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INSERT RAW DATA HERE").getRange(3,5,300,4).getValues();
 
  var day = dateStr.substring(0,2);
  var month = dateStr.substring(3,5);
  var year = "20"+dateStr.substring(6,8);
  var weekNumb = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(year, month-1, day), "GMT", "w");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("WEEKNUMBERS").getRange(3,5,300,4).setValues(weekNumb);
   
 }
```

It worked perfectly with a foor loop, converting each single value at a time. But it was super slow. My problem lays in using the ".substring()" formula for arrays, it does not seem to work..
Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: are the values in the sheet legit date objects? does `=date(A1)` returns true for a date stored in cell A1 ?

Comment: no, unfortunately they are seen as text (because the input date format is wrong already)

Answer (score 0):

The use of substring() is not possible when applying directly to an array. Looping the only way in getting the substring() of each element on an array.

### Suggestion

If you are open to changing the data in your sheet, you can try using createTextFinder(".").replaceAllWithText("/") on your data range to convert your data to date format. Once you have this, you will still loop into your new data to get the week number of each date. Code is as follows and this is working on my end:

```
function CheckWeekNuber() {
   
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INSERT RAW DATA HERE").getRange(3,5,300,4);
  range.createTextFinder(".").replaceAllWith("/") // converts str date to date format
  var dateFormat = range.getValues();
  var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = range.getLastColumn();
  var weekNumb = [];
  for(var row in dateFormat){
    for(var column in dateFormat[row]){
      dateFormat[row][column] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateFormat[row][column]), "GMT", "w");
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("WEEKNUMBERS").getRange(3,5,300,4).setValues(dateFormat);
}
```